# Android - Setting bitmap collision detection after rotation by matrix

Tags: android, matrix, collision-detection

How do I create code for collision detection on a bitmap rotated by a matrix?

```
canvas.drawBitmap(mAnimation, mainMatrix, null);
```

mainMatrix is derived from a PathMeasure so i do not know the rotation
The bitmap is rotated around x=0,y=0  and thus a circle around the centre will not work (or at least be too big)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matrix has a method to map points and rectangles, you could use that to know the result of the transformation.